# Not like the one in Texas

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme, anagram, literature

> I... **PILFER AND MASK** (or **SKIMP AND FLARE**)
> I also... **BOB A GRANNY THERE**
> I... **USE A PRISON** and **APE OUR SINS**
> I'm often... **EYELESS AND SIT IN BINS**
> I... **PIPED CURD AND I JEER**, you see...
> At the end of the day, well, I... **AM ME**!

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> Jane Austen

Why?

> Each block of highlighted text is an anagram (or two) of a Jane Austen novel:
>  - Mansfield Park
>  - Northanger Abbey
>  - Persuasion
>  - Sense and Sensibility
>  - Pride and Prejudice
>  - Emma

And for the title (credit to @Prim3numbah for pointing out what I missed):

> Austen isn't quite like Austin (Texas)

Comment: this fits well with the title too rot13((Nhfgra naq abg *Nhfgva*, Grknf))

Comment: Nicely solved, well done :) Perhaps you could also mention the intended title reference as per the comment by @Prim3numbah above?

Comment: Now perfect, the checkmark is yours :)